# How to merge 2 Shapely objects?

Tags: python, merge, shapely

I try to merge two [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union) Objects in my Python Project. 
There is a sort of kind of manual that describes some features of Shapely such as `cascaded_union()` but I that only works for Polygons. The `shapely.ops.unary_union()` method should work for other geometries as well but I can't get it to work.

In a nutshell: how do I merge 2 LinearRing Objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I actually solved the problem myself.

```
p1 = Polygon(ring.coords) 
p2 = Polygon(ring2.coords)
```

to make polygons from my rings. then I create an array with those polygons. merge them with cascaded_union and create a LinearRing from the new polygon.

```
pols = [p1, p2] 
new_pol = ops.cascaded_union(pols) 
new_ring = LinearRing(new_pol.exterior.coords)
```

Comment: When you create polygons from linear rings, operate on them and then put the result back into a polygon you pretty much know you do a bad job of progamming and don't have readable code anymore.

I actually changed my whole project to have polygons instead of linear rings. That's because I realized, that you can't use most of the "crosses" "intersects" etc methods on LinearRings. But on Polygons you can. So choose wisely! If you use Shapely and you want to check objects for "inside" "outside" you pretty much need polygons.

Comment: I was searching for ways of extracting points from a polygon, and your answer helped. For the given example you can do this by `poly_x, poly_y = new_pol.exterior.coords.xy`. Thanks.

Comment: `cascaded_union` has since been depreciated. The use of [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) is recommended instead.